# Question regarding: Quill js, Quill-Image-Resize and PHP-Quill-Renderer

Tags: php, quill

I have implemented [Quill's WYSIWYG editor](https://github.com/quilljs) on my website. With that, I also wanted an image resizer, and many people recommended [this component](https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module). I also installed [PHP Quill Renderer](https://github.com/deanblackborough/php-quill-renderer) to translate Quill's Delta into HTML.

I tested everything and it works fine (the data I receive from the renderer corresponds to the data I posted with the form).

However, if I *resize* an image in the Quill editor and send it to the renderer, I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DBlackborough\Quill\Delta\Html\Insert::__construct() must be of the type string, array given, called in ...... on line 22
```

I checked the file and this function was on line 22:

```
public function __construct(string $insert, array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->tag = null;

    $this->insert = $insert;
    $this->attributes = $attributes;
}
```

As a beginner to all of this, I do not know what I should do. I assume that because I am using an external component (i.e. **Quill Image Resizer**) which was not part of **Quill js**, the developer of the **Php Quill Renderer** did not add support for *image resizing*.

Can anybody guide me through the steps I should take to correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, here is how I corrected it

**Information about the problem:**

The attribute `width="xx"` is inserted by `Quill Image Resizer` plugin when you resize the image. However in `PHP Quill Renderer`, Parse does not know this attribute, being associated with no Delta uses the default.

```
switch ($attribute) {
    default:
        $this->insert($quill);
        break;
}
```

**Solution:**

To correct this problem we need to add a new `width` constant in the options and then in parse we need to add a new `case` to link this constant to the image.

*page : Options.php (ligne : 50)*

```
public const ATTRIBUTE_WIDTH = 'width';
public const ATTRIBUTE_ALT = 'alt';
```

*page : Parser/Parse.php (ligne : 179)*

```
case Options::ATTRIBUTE_WIDTH:
    $this->image($quill);
    break;
case Options::ATTRIBUTE_ALT:
    $this->image($quill);
    break;
```

Not sure this is the best solution, but it fixes the problem and no change is to be made to the basic functions. As you can see in my code I also add the `alt` attribute to associate it with the image. It may be as profitable for you

Good luck !

Comment: I'm a bit late seeing this but if this still a problem create an issue on the repo and I'll fix it. Alternatively, raise a PR and I'll merge in your fix.